# React Element getting rendered even after change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, react-component

I am new to React but I am having a problem with this simple app

I am trying to add a search functionality but whenever I search the search element results are gets rendered

and when I remove everything from the search box all elements display as intended

But the previously rendered search elements are also there with all the list

**Logic Example :**

Like I searched for A from [A.B.C] and render A then when I remove A from the search box it renders all A,B,C but also previous render A also stays in end so the complete rendered list goes like A.B.C.A

I need a way to remove this searched A or just one time render these searched element

I need to remove these Rendered elements anyhow or hide them or anyhow only display only all elements

Here is my App.js

```
import React , {useState , useEffect} from 'react'
import RecipieList from "./RecipieList";
import RecipieEdit from './RecipieEdit';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import Search from './Search';
import "../css/app.css"

export const RecipieContext = React.createContext()

const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "cookingwithreact.app.recipies"

function App() {
  const storedRecipies = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)) ;
  const [selectedRecipieId , setSelectedRecipie] = useState("")
  const [search , setSearch] = useState(undefined)

  if(storedRecipies.length < 1){
    constRecipies.forEach((constRecipie)=>{
      storedRecipies.push(constRecipie)
    })
  }

  const [recipies , setRecipies] = useState(storedRecipies)
  const selectedRecipie = recipies.find(recipie => recipie.id === selectedRecipieId)
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    const recipeJSON = localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)
    if(recipeJSON !=null) setRecipies(JSON.parse(recipeJSON))
  },[])

  useEffect(()=>{
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY , JSON.stringify([...recipies]))
  },[recipies])
  
  const recipieContextValue = {
    handleRecipieAdd,
    handleRecipieSelect,
    handleRecipieChange,
    handleRecipieDelete
  }
  
  function handleRecipieChange(id,editedRecipie){
    const newRecipies = [...recipies]
    const index = newRecipies.findIndex(e => e.id === id)
    newRecipies[index] = editedRecipie
    setRecipies(newRecipies)
  }

  function handleRecipieSelect(id){
    setSelectedRecipie(id)
  }

  function handleRecipieAdd(){
    let newRecipie = {
      id:uuidv4(),
      name:"",
      cookTime:"",
      servings : "",
      instructions : "",
      items:[
        {
          id:uuidv4(),
          name:"",
          amount:""
        }
      ]
    }
    handleRecipieSelect(newRecipie.id)
    setRecipies([...recipies,newRecipie])
  }

  function handleRecipieDelete (id){
    if(selectedRecipieId !=null && selectedRecipieId === id){
      setSelectedRecipie(undefined)
    }
    setRecipies(recipies.filter(recipie => recipie.id !== id))
  }

  return (
      <RecipieContext.Provider value={recipieContextValue}>
        <Search recipies={recipies} recipieContextValue={recipieContextValue} setSearch = {setSearch}></Search>
        {!search && <RecipieList recipies={recipies} ></RecipieList>}
        {selectedRecipie && <RecipieEdit recipie = {selectedRecipie}/>}
      </RecipieContext.Provider>  )
}

export let constRecipies = [
  {
    id : 1,
    name:"Poha",
    cookTime:"00:10",
    servings : "2",
    instructions : "1. Take Poha \n2. Make Poha \n3. Eat Poha",
    items : [
      {
        id:1,
        name:"Poha",
        amount:"1 Packet"
      },
      {
        id:2,
        name:"Namkeen",
        amount:"2 Packet"
      },
      {
        id:3,
        name:"Spices",
        amount:"3 Packet"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id : 2,
    name:"Maggi",
    cookTime:"00:20",
    servings : "3",
    instructions : " 1. Take Maggi \n 2. Make Maggi \n 3. Eat Maggi",
    items : [
      {
        id:1,
        name:"Maggi",
        amount:"1 Packet"
      },
      {
        id:2,
        name:"Veges",
        amount:"1 Packet"
      },
      {
        id:3,
        name:"Spices",
        amount:"1 Packet"
      }
    ]
  },
]

export default App;
```

and here is Search.js

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React  from 'react';
import RecipieSearchList from './RecipieSearchList';
import RecipieList from './RecipieList'

export default function Search(props) {
    const {recipies , setSearch ,recipieContextValue} = props

    function handleSearch(searchedTerm){
        
        if(searchedTerm.length > 0){
            let foundedRecipies = recipies.filter(element => element.name.includes(searchedTerm));
            console.log(foundedRecipies)
            setSearch("defined")
            render(
                <RecipieSearchList recipieContextValue={recipieContextValue} recipies={foundedRecipies}/>
            )

        }
        else{
            console.log("Search is Empty")
            setSearch(undefined)
        }
    }

  return (
      <>
      <div className='search-container'>
          <input 
          onChange={(e)=>{handleSearch(e.target.value)}} 
          className='search-field' placeholder='Search' 
          type="text" id='search'/>
      </div>
      </>
  )
}
```

Here is the [Github Link](https://github.com/iovvb/cookwithreact)

Comment: Set search as a prop to  search component then it may be work.  const {recipies,...search} = props

Comment: where in App.js

Comment: No in search.js

Comment: But I am not using it in search.js anywhere

Comment: The Main Problem is Whenever I search the searched components get rendered here with RecipieSearchList but when I remove all chars from search bar that rendered component remains there and I cant remove it

Comment: Now I got your point.It is because previously rendered component life cycle not yet ended.It cause of adding multiple elemnt to dom without destroying previous ones.Then you get reciecomponent outside from the handle change method and pass that to app.However in this time you have to maintain the loop inside  app component.Inside receipe component it  only render one search elemnt result.

Comment: Yes exactly I want anyhow to remove these rendered Searched Recipes

Comment: If the parent component rerendered children components as well as previos parent components get destroyed.In current implementation reciepcomponent has no parent.

Comment: If anyhow I can re-render my app.js then it can work but I cant find any way to do so

Comment: You've got some odd stuff in your code, like a `render` function from `react-testing-library`. From what I see here you've also got what appears to be some duplicate component/element/data rendering. Can you try creating a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue we could inspect live?

Comment: Here is the GitHub link it can't seem to create the codesandbox https://github.com/iovvb/cookwithreact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Guys i found a workaround of the problem that instead of rendering if I return it should work fine

The Probelm I was having is with logic

Here is the code I came up with is to check from the beginning if there is already available recipes or not

```
      recipes.filter((val)=>{
          if(search == ""){
              return val
          }
          else if(val.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase())){
              return val
          }
      }).map((recipe,key)=>{
          return <Recipe key={key} recipe={recipe}></Recipe>
      })
```